# what makes two python files import a same config file and can influence each other?

Tags: python, import

maybe this tiltle cannot explain my questions, here has an example.

There are three python files, `demo.py`、`fun.py`、`config.py`.

in the `config.py` file:

```
from easydict import EasyDict as edict

__C = edict()
cfg = __C
__C.TRAIN = edict()
__C.TRAIN.LEARNING_RATE = 0.001
```

in the `fun.py`:

```
from config import cfg
def function():
    print(cfg.TRAIN.LEARNING_RATE)
    cfg.TRAIN.LEARNING_RATE = 1
    pass
```

in the `demo.py`:

```
from config import cfg
from fun import function

cfg.TRAIN.LEARNING_RATE = 0.1

function()

print(cfg.TRAIN.LEARNING_RATE)
```

run the `demo.py`,results in :

```
0.1
1
```

I am curious about why `fun.py` can change the values in the `demo.py` although they import a same config file.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you answered your own question: they import the same config file.

Keep in mind you're not changing a value in `demo.py` or `fun.py`. Instead, when you do `cfg.TRAIN.LEARNING_RATE = 0.1` you're changing the variable in memory `cfg`, which is tied to `config.py`.

Since both `demo.py` and `fun.py` import the same `config.py`, the interpreter loads the whole thing into memory once and gives those other two files access to the `cfg` variable stored in memory. In other words, they're both manipulating the same variable, which they accessed independently.

(The reason the program never outputs `0.001` is that, while `cfg.TRAIN.LEARNING_RATE` is initialized to that value as soon as you load `config.py` into memory for the first time, you never actually print it before reassigning it to `0.1`.)

Comment: It is not as obvious as you suggest it, if I change the files to :
`config.py` file:

    var = 0.001

`fun.py`:

    from config import var
    def function():
        print(var)
        var = 1

`demo.py`:

    from config import var
    from fun import function

    var = 0.1

    function()

    print(var)

I get :
    UnboundLocalError: local variable 'var' referenced before assignment
Adding a `global var` to `fun.py` give the expected result.